# Removing Headers from CSV files

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have some line of codes which was supposed to help remove headers from all

CSV files present in my working directory.

Unfortunately after running these codes I got an error on the 10th line

What could have lead to this error?

Thanks in advance.

Below are the codes:

```
import csv,os

os.makedirs('headerRemoved',exist_ok=True)

for csvFilename in os.listdir('.'):

    if not  csvFilename.endswith('.csv'):

        continue     

 print('Removing header from ' + csvFilename + '...')

csvRows=[]

csvFileObj=open(csvFilename)

readerObj=csv.reader(csvFileObj)

for row in readerObj:

    if readObj.line_num==1:

        continue     

csvRows.append(row)

csvFileObj.close()

for csvFilename in os.listdir('.'):

    if not csvFilename.endswith('.csv'):

        continue       

csvFileObj=open(os.path.join('headerRemoved',csvFilename), 'w',newline='')

csvWriter =CSV.writer(csvFileObj)

for row in csvRows:

    csvWriter.writerow(row)


csvFileObj.close()
```

I expected to get newly created CSV rows without headers stored in "headerRemoved",but I  got the following output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)

      <ipython-input-36-5b7fd957ccb0> in <module>()

      8 # Read the CSV file(skipping the first row).

      9 csvRows=[]

---> 10 csvFileObj=open(csvFilename)

     11 readerObj=csv.reader(csvFileOb)

     12 for row in readerObj:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '__pycache__'
```

Comment: Did you recently run some code in this directory as root / administrator? It looks like `__pycache__`, or maybe your current directory, is not writable because it was created with by a different user (likely root) .

Comment: Make sure you have closed the file before running the code. I mean to say dont open it in WPS or Microsoft Excel, anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

If your indentation is as shown, then you loop through all the files in the first for loop before proceeding to the file processing section, so `csvFilename` is the last result of `os.listdir('.')`, which happens to be the directory `__pycache__` and directories can't be opened like a file, hence the permission error.  To fix it, indent the later code into the for loop as shown below (and a little refactoring):

```
import csv,os

os.makedirs('headerRemoved',exist_ok=True)

for csvFilename in os.listdir('.'):
    if not csvFilename.endswith('.csv'):
        continue

    print('Removing header from ' + csvFilename + '...')

    with open(csvFilename,'r',newline='') as infile:
        with open(os.path.join('headerRemoved',csvFilename),'w',newline='') as outfile:
            r = csv.reader(infile)
            w = csv.writer(outfile)
            next(r) # skip first row
            for row in r:
                w.writerow(row)
```

Comment: @ Mark Tolonnen,thanks for answering and simplifying the solution.

Comment: @Loui Welcome to SO! If the answer is useful, consider upvoting and accepting it as the answer via the controls on the left.

Comment: @ Mark Tolonen considering my personality which includes appreciation,I would have loved to upvote but I need 15 more reputations to be able to upvote.Whenever I achieve my reputation be rest assured that I will upvote,because this answer needs to be upvoted for future participants.Thanks

Comment: Thanks, great solution. Worked for me.